# How to enable VK_KHR_maintenance2 vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to create `VkImageView` which will be binded to index 0.

Here is my `VkImageView` creation code

```
void Image::createImageView() {
VkImageViewUsageCreateInfo imageViewUsage;
imageViewUsage.sType=VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_USAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageViewUsage.pNext=nullptr;
imageViewUsage.usage=VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT;


VkImageViewCreateInfo viewInfo{};
viewInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
viewInfo.pNext=&imageViewUsage;
viewInfo.image = textureImage;
viewInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
viewInfo.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
viewInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
viewInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
viewInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

if (vkCreateImageView(device, &viewInfo, nullptr, &textureImageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture image view!");
}

}
```

When I call `vkUpdateDescriptorSets` I get validation error:

```
vkCreateImageView: Includes a pNext pointer (pCreateInfo->pNext) to a VkStructureType (VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_USAGE_CREATE_INFO), but its parent extension VK_KHR_maintenance2 has not been enabled. The Vulkan spec states: Each pNext member of any structure (including this one) in the pNext chain must be either NULL or a pointer to a valid instance of VkImageViewASTCDecodeModeEXT, VkImageViewUsageCreateInfo, VkSamplerYcbcrConversionInfo, VkVideoProfileKHR, or VkVideoProfilesKHR
```

Before this I had set `viewInfo.pNext=nullptr;` for which I was getting validation error:

```
Write update to VkDescriptorSet 0xf018750000000004[] allocated with VkDescriptorSetLayout 0x683e70000000002[] binding #0 failed with error message: Attempted write update to image descriptor failed due to: ImageView (VkImageView 0xa3c6870000000008[]) with usage mask 0x6 being used for a descriptor update of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_STORAGE_IMAGE does not have VK_IMAGE_USAGE_STORAGE_BIT set
```

Can someone please help me with some hint how exactly I can solve the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what to do. If you use `VkImageViewUsageCreateInfo`, that means you have to enable maintenance2 extension or in turn Vulkan 1.1 to which it was promoted.

Since you seem surprised by the existence of extensions, it feels likely your use of them is just accidental. You might simply want to stop using the `VkImageViewUsageCreateInfo` extension struct and always set `pNext` to `NULL`.

Comment: Can you tell how do that? I couldn't find docs on that

Comment: Feels like it might be a XY problem. Why are you using extensions if you do not even know what extensions are?

Comment: But anyway `VK_KHR_maintenance2` is a device extension that can be enabled at [vkCreateDevice](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkCreateDevice) time by adding it to its appropriate argument (assuming the device supports the extension). Or alternatively core version can be enabled by `VkApplicationInfo::apiVersion` at `vkCreateInstance` time, and both instance and device need to support the version as queried by `vkEnumerateInstanceVersion` and `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties::apiVersion`.